# How to allow a specific port in Google Cloud Platform instance for the specific URL/IP

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, firewall, rules

Instead of allowing for all, I just want to open the port for the specific IP/URL, How we can do this in Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: If you want to limit access to your GCE VM instance you can [mark it with a network tag](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags#adding_new_tags_to_vm_instances) and [create a GCP firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/configuring-firewall#creating_a_firewall_ingress_rule) to limit access by the particular IP. Alternatively, you can try GCP WAF [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/). Please let me know if any of solution mentioned above is suitable for you.

Comment: You can only limit by IP with firewall rules. With Cloud Armor, I'm sure you can check the header values to allow/block according with the host name, but it's not very safe and secure.

Comment: can't we do this in firewall rules?

Comment: With GCP firewall you can allow access from the specific IP.

Comment: 1/2) Google Cloud VPC Firewall rules operate at the OSI Model Layer 3. That means only IP addresses in the packet headers can be processed. Domain names and URLs have been translated to IP addresses long before arriving at the VPC therefore the firewall cannot process (allow/block) what it cannot see.

Comment: 2/2) HTTP operates at Layer 6/7. Even if the VPC firewall were to decode packet data to analyze at higher layers to look for URLs, there is no guarantee that the data is not encrypted thereby rending such a rule unenforceable. Decoding packets is much slower and requires complicated software. Comparing IP headers can be performed by hardware/firmware at wire speed.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already discussed at the comment section, you can use [Google Cloud Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) which operates on the Level 3 to [create a rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) and allow access from the particular IP addresses:

> Firewall rules are defined at the network level, and only apply to the network where they are created.

If you require URL filtration on the Level 6/7 you can have a look on the Google Cloud [Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall) - [Google Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/).